# AWS QuickSight filtering based on result of a query or other dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I want to create an analysis table in AWS Quicksight that shows the quantity sold in a given month and it's subsequent month based on users who made a purchase on the given month.

Let's say I have a dataset called `user_orders` with the following data:

```
+---------+----------+------------+
| user_id | quantity | order_date |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 1       |    2     | 2020-04-01 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 1       |    3     | 2020-04-02 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 1       |    1     | 2020-05-23 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 1       |    2     | 2020-06-02 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 2       |    1     | 2020-05-03 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 2       |    1     | 2020-05-04 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 3       |    2     | 2020-04-07 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 3       |    1     | 2020-04-10 |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 3       |    1     | 2020-06-23 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

For example, using the table above I want to be able to show how many quantities sold in April, May, June, and so on (max 12 months) by users who made a purchase in April.
The resulting table should look like this:

```
+-----------+----------+
|           | quantity |
+-----------+----------+
| 04-2020   | 8        |
+-----------+----------+
| 05-2020   | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 06-2020   | 3        |
+-----------+----------+
```

- 8 sold in April because user_id 1 made 5 purchase and user_id 3 made 3 purchase while user_id 2 did not make any purchase.
- There is only 1 item sold in May because only user_id 1 made the purchase in May, but also made a purchase in April. user_id 2 also made a purchase in May but didn't in April so it's not counted.

I can make the table above using PHP and MySQL fairly easily using the following code:

```
# first get all the user ids who made a purchase in April
$user_ids = sql_query("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-30'");

# get the quantity sold for each month by users who made a purchase in April
$purchases = sql_query("SELECT MONTH(order_date), SUM(quantity) FROM user_orders WHERE user_id IN ({$user_ids}) AND order_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2021-03-31' GROUP BY MONTH(order_date);")
```

(Obviously, April is just an example, I'd like to be able to change the starting month dynamically using QuickSight control)

As my above example shown, it requires two queries to perform this analysis. First, is to get the user_ids of the users, and the next is to actually get the quantity sold by the users.

I have been trying to achieve this using Quicksight for the last 3 days but hasn't found any way yet.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a calculated field like this and filtering on it

distinctCountOver(ifelse(truncDate('MM', {order_Date}) = parseDate('2020-04-01'), 1, NULL), [{user_id}], PRE_AGG)

(ofcourse, you can change the parseDate portion to be your date parameter)

Now, lets say the name of the above calculated field is SpecificMonthUser. You can add a filter sum(SpecificMonthUser) != 0.

And then create a pivot table visualization with OrderDate, user id in the rows and sum(quantity) in the values. You should get the desired result.